# Regex replace with separate replacement depending on the match

Tags: c#, regex, replace, pattern-matching

Suppose if I have a dictionary (**word** and its replacements) as :

```
var replacements = new Dictionary<string,string>();
replacements.Add("str", "string0");
replacements.Add("str1", "string1");
replacements.Add("str2", "string2");
...
```

and an input string as :

```
 string input = @"@str is a #str is a [str1] is a &str1 @str2 one test $str2 also [str]";
```

**Edit**:
Expected output :

```
string0 is a string0 is string0 is string1 string2 one test string2
```

I want to replace all occurances of '**[CharSymbol]word**'  with its **corresponding** entry/value from the dictionary.

where **Charsymbol** can be @#$%^&*[] .. and also  ']' after the word is valid i.e. [str] .

I tried the following for replace

```
string input = @"@str is a #str is a [str1] is a &str1 @str2 one test $str2 also [str]"; 
string pattern = @"(([@$&#\[]+)([a-zA-Z])*(\])*)"; // correct?
Regex re = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
// string outputString = re.Replace(input,"string0"); 
 string newString = re.Replace(input, match =>   
         {  
             Debug.WriteLine(match.ToString()); // match is [str] #str 
             string lookup = "~"; // default value
             replacements.TryGetValue(match.Value,out lookup);
             return lookup;
         });
```

How do i get the match as str , str1 etc. i.e. word without charsymbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex to this:

```
// Move the * inside the brackets around [a-zA-Z]
// Change [a-zA-Z] to \w, to include digits.
string pattern = @"(([@$&#\[]+)(\w*)(\])*)";
```

Change this line:

```
replacements.TryGetValue(match.Value,out lookup);
```

to this:

```
replacements.TryGetValue(match.Groups[3].Value,out lookup);
```

Note: Your `IgnoreCase` isn't necessary, since you match both upper and lower case in the regex.

Comment: nope..now it gives "string0 is a string0 is a str1] is a str2 str1 can be done string0 is str2"

Comment: I missed the fact that [a-zA-Z] doesn't match digits. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Does this suit?

```
(?<=[#@&$])(\w+)|[[\w+]]
```

It matches the following in your example:

@`str` is a #`str` is a [`str`] is a &`str1` @`str2` one test $`str2`

Comment: no sorry doesnt work as expected.. i have updated the question to show how i did the match/replace.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `Regex`: `([@$&#\[])[a-zA-Z]*(\])?`, and replace with `string0`

your code should be like this:

```
var replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                            {"str", "string0"},
                            {"str1", "string1"},
                            {"str2", "string2"}
                        };

String input="@str is a #str is a [str] is a &str @str can be done $str is @str";

foreach (var replacement in replacements)
{
    string pattern = String.Format(@"([@$&#\[]){0}(\])?", replacement.Key);
    var re = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    string output = re.Replace(input, 
                               String.Format("{0}", replacement.Value)); 
}
```

Comment: sorry doesn't work for the input string in the question.ie. "@str is a #str is a [str1] is a &str1 @str2 one test $str2 also [str]"